# Designing equipment enclosure and using anti-tamper earthing bolts

Tags: grounding

A bolt head is often seen on the outside of the enclosure of many devices (e.g. power supplies), marked as earth bonds. The head of the bolts I am referring to does not have the usual drive geometry, so that it is difficult or impossible for the user to loosen them.

This makes sense for safety reasons (if the bolt is removed, earthing of the enclosure may fail and safety would be compromised).

Could someone please provide some rationale as to when/why protruding plugs/bolts, as opposed to other solutions, would make sense in earthing an enclosure?

Comment: Have earth-connection bolts welded inside the enclosure when it is manufactured. This is industry practice.  Nothing protrudes from the outside of the enclosure.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Isn't the possibility of earth equalization often advantageous (which would require an externally accessible earth plug)?

Comment: I would expect an Earth Bond bolt to be easily tightened by the installer - otherwise, how is he going to attach the earth wire?  Perhaps the bolt or screw heads you've seen are Torx head or other less common, but readily available, type that the average homeowner won't have in his toolbox.

Comment: Thanks Peter. In the case of medical devices, safety regulations prohibit earthing bolts that could be easily loosened/tightened from the outside. Earth connection must be done inside the enclosure. An externally accessible plug is allowed though, but should not be easy to loosen. My question was originally about types of (safe) earth plugs and I re-edited to request a comparison with welding an internal flange.